# laCie 1TB USB3.0 not detected in windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb-3, hardware-detection, lacie

I have a problem with my laCie rugged USB3.0 1TB. When I connect it via USB2.0 it works correctly according to USB2.0 specifications.

Recently, I have bought a USB3.0 adapter and when I connect the drive to it, it does not appear in the list of drives in system. Adapter works, so does the HDD connected to USB2.0. I also tried different USB3.0 HDDs, pen-drives, cables, different USB3.0 ports to test the adapter and it does work with different devices. My HDD USB3.0 however does not appear in the system when I connect it to USB3.0 adapter.

There's no extra drivers for this HDD on manufacturer website. There's a link to driver for Thunderbolt port but my drive has only USB3.0 port.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the adapter card to work or how to get the hdd to work?  If the hdd is transfer data slower that is a sign the hdd is experiencing a hardware failure.

Comment: I have reworded the question.
I am asking if someone can help or had a similar problem. This is relatively old HDD (2-3 yo) but is supposed to work with USB3.0 and it does not. I am wondering what is the reason. The card is OK, so are cables -- checked. Somehow my HDD has problem with USB3.0 when it should not.